# About the name of a sin

Tags: sin

I thought that the word Greatest and God cannot be used together in a sentence because the meaning might come out wrong
So I used to avoid saying “Allah is the Greatest God”
Rather used to say them separately like
“Allah is the Greatest and He is the only God”
Does this make me a sinner ?
And if so
What is the name of the sin?

Comment: Why would it be a sin?

Comment: It isn’t right?

Answer (score 0):

*“Allah is the Greatest and only God”* is way more better and accurate than *“Allah is the Greatest God”*

What you used to do was better and it is not a sin.

Why you stopped adding 'only', I suggest keep adding 'only'.